# How to download a file as a browser

Tags: java, http, file-io

If I save an mp3 file via a browser, the third-party library is normally working with him, if I shake myself through HTTP, then the third-party library with him unable to work due to not correctly encoded.

I use this code

```
HttpGet first = new HttpGet(url);

first.addHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(first, localContext);
InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
    sb.append(line);
}

instream.close();
String textFile = sb.toString();

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test123.mp3"));
out.write(textFile);
out.close();
```

What's wrong?

maybe it encoded

Comment: You could try comparing the HTTP sessions with Fiddler.

Comment: Your English is bad and hard to understand.

Comment: Zian Choy, Why? I get work file. I can played this file.

Comment: Robin Green, Thanks. I know that my English is bad. I need to download the file, since it would have made the browser.

Answer (score 6):

You're treating a binary file as text file by using `Reader`/`Writer` instead of `InputStream`/`OutputStream`. The `BufferedReader#readLine()` eats CRLF bytes.

Just write `InputStream` to `OutputStream` directly without massaging the bytes to characters and back and removing CRLF bytes. You also don't need to worry about character encoding anymore.

```
InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test123.mp3");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > -1;) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

output.close();
input.close();
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Essential Classes - Basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem relies on the fact that you are writing your file as a Character file, not a binary one. Try reading this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/TheuseofDataOutputStreamandDataInputStream.htm and this http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't read a String for binary content. Won't work.

And here is my obligatory advertisement for the free, open-source alternative to messing around with HTTPClient or URLConnection yourself.

```
Resty r = new Resty();
File f = r.bytes(url).save(new File("test123.mp3"));
```

Resty is available here http://beders.github.com/Resty 
(DISCLAIMER: I'm the maintainer of this little side project)